# Select checkbox using selenium in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to select a checkbox using selenium in python. Following is the HTML of the checkbox. The span element is getting highlighted when hovering the mouse over checkbox

HTML

```
<div id="rc-anchor-container" class="rc-anchor rc-anchor-normal rc-anchor-light">
    <div id="recaptcha-accessible-status" class="rc-anchor-aria-status" aria-hidden="true">Recaptcha requires verification. </div>
    <div class="rc-anchor-error-msg-container" style="display:none"><span class="rc-anchor-error-msg" aria-hidden="true"></span></div>
    <div class="rc-anchor-content">
        <div class="rc-inline-block">
            <div class="rc-anchor-center-container">
                <div class="rc-anchor-center-item rc-anchor-checkbox-holder"><span class="recaptcha-checkbox goog-inline-block recaptcha-checkbox-unchecked rc-anchor-checkbox" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" id="recaptcha-anchor" tabindex="0" dir="ltr" aria-labelledby="recaptcha-anchor-label"><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-border" role="presentation"></div><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-borderAnimation" role="presentation"></div><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-spinner" role="presentation"></div><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-spinnerAnimation" role="presentation"></div><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark" role="presentation"></div></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rc-inline-block">
            <div class="rc-anchor-center-container">
                <label class="rc-anchor-center-item rc-anchor-checkbox-label" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" id="recaptcha-anchor-label"><span aria-live="polite" aria-labelledby="recaptcha-accessible-status"></span>I'm not a robot</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rc-anchor-normal-footer">
        <div class="rc-anchor-logo-portrait" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation">
            <div class="rc-anchor-logo-img rc-anchor-logo-img-portrait"></div>
            <div class="rc-anchor-logo-text">reCAPTCHA</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rc-anchor-pt"><a href="https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/privacy/" target="_blank">Privacy</a><span aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"> - </span><a href="https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/" target="_blank">Terms</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying the following code but it is giving following exception `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException`

My Code

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chromedriver = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\chromedriver'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
browser.get(url)

checkBox = browser.find_element_by_id("recaptcha-anchor")
checkBox.click()
```

Comment: @Pratik I added `time.sleep(10)` after `browser.get(url)` still not working.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the `url` as I think you have to select `div` not the `span`

Comment: Here is the URL https://portal.zinghr.com/2015/pages/authentication/login.aspx

Comment: So as I said `div` is the one you should select. You can use xpath= `.//div[@class='recaptcha-checkbox-border']`

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: Where do you see the id "recaptcha-anchor" in the HTML you posted? I think your locator is wrong. If it wasn't a screenshot, we could actually do a text search and find it easier...

Comment: @JeffC sorry my bad I edited the question

Comment: @Pratik I am still getting `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException` after trying with xpath

Comment: Try to use WebDriverWait:
https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a recaptha stuff .. it's not like normal elements in the page

you have to navigate with selenium to the captcha frame .. then you can deal with the checkbox element..

to do that you need first to save the main window handle to be get back to it when you're done with the recaptcha

```
# save the main window handle
mainwindow = browser.current_window_handle

# get the recapthca iframe then navigate to it
frame = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")  
browser.switch_to.frame(frame)

# now you can access the checkbox element 
browser.find_element_by_id("recaptcha-anchor").click()

# navigate back to main window
browser.switch_to.window(mainwindow)
```

for further info about how to deal with the recaptcha challenge check this [link](http://scraping.pro/recaptcha-solve-selenium-python/)